# Радиус окружности зоны влияния в методе интерполяции естественного соседа

Tags: python, алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь сделать интерполяцию естественного соседа с помощью ячеек Вороного. В качестве зоны влияния я использую не ячейки Вороного а окружности. На картинке которую я прикрепил написано что радиус этой окружности задаётся как расстояние до k естественного соседа, как понять какое это расстояние? Я брал максимальный радиус до естественного соседа получалось плохо, минимальный радиус дал некоторый результат, но хотелось бы точно узнать какой это радиус

Comment: Судя по рисунку, имеются в виду вершины. Выстраиваем их по увеличению расстояния от данной точки, и расстояние до k-ой вершины в этом списке и есть R. На рисунке не очень четко видно, но k то ли 8, то ли 9...

Comment: Интересное предположение, но я думаю что если бы расстояние было до вершины, то зачем писали про расстояние до естественного соседа(точки у которой общие грани с иследуемой точкой )

Comment: Я исхожу из поясняющего рисунка.